# How to remove the null values from an array containing multiple arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that consists of a list of arrays. I want to delete the null elements from my array.
The below picture is the array.
What I want is if the date is null, then the whole part with the value should be removed from the array.

```
Original Array = [
   [[value:null, data:Alcohol],[value:null, data:null]],
   [[value:Test, date:Wed],[value:Test2, date:null]],
   [[value:Test3, date:null],[value:Test4, date:Wed]],
   [[value:Test5, date:Wed],[value:Test6, date:null]]
];

Final Array ​= [
  ​[[value:null, data:Alcohol]],
  ​[[value:Test, date:Wed]],
  ​[[value:Test3, date:null]],
  ​[[value:Test5, date:Wed]]
];
```

The original Array

[image: The original Array]

After removing the null values, I need it to be like the below image.

The array show be after

[image: The array show be after]

Comment: Could you parse the actual json here so everyone can use it to help you better? Anyway, an Array.map() function would do it.

Comment: Can you post the example array in code instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Could you please provide the data as actual valid JS code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the outer array to a new array, and use a filter on the nested/inner arrays to filter out elements with a null `date` property.

```
const newData = data.map(el => el.filter(({ date }) => date !== null));
```

```js
const data = [
   [{value:null, data:'Alcohol'},{value:null, data:null}],
   [{value:'Test', date:'Wed'},{value:'Test2', date:null}],
   [{value:'Test3', date:null},{value:'Test4', date:'Wed'}],
   [{value:'Test5', date:'Wed'},{value:'Test6', date:null}]
]

const newData = data.map(el => el.filter(({ date }) => date !== null));

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: @ParulRanjan Is it not already?  Are there specific objects you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Something like a `filter` into a `map`:

```
yourArray.map(x => x.filter(y => y.date !== null))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [1, 2, null, 4, null, 6]
const filtered = array.filter(item => item !== null)
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: You don't actually need to check if item !== null. You can just return item :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir unless you don't want to filter out falsy items that aren't null

Comment: Yeah but there are more situations where you do want to also filter them out than the other way around :)